# select option:checked background color change but option text color not change in css

Tags: html, css

select option:checked background color perfect work but option text color not work please help me

CSS code

```
<style>
        select option:checked{
            background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);
            color: #000 ! important;
        }
   </style>
```

HTML code

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

please ans me
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try updating color as

color: #000 ! important;

Yes working for me. Once focus out from select it will work.
[Please check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKXJX.png)

Comment: Yes working for me.
Once focus out from select it will work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
<select multiple class="select_option_class_name">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>



$('.select_option_class_name').change(function () {

   $(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
   $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', 'red');
}).trigger('change');
```

I think this is what you really want

```
<style>
    .select_option_class_name{
        color:red;
        background-color:red;

    }

</style>
```

Comment: no color change background color change but option text color not change

Comment: have you added the class in select

Comment: yes but not work background color change with need option text color change but after option text color change

Comment: cant understand what you are saying

Comment: option:checked background color change perfect work but font color not chagned

Comment: try using the below <style> code also because the jquery should change your selected text color but it will not change the color of select box text

Comment: i think the problem is with you select box having multiple option

Comment: please give me option:checked event example to option text color change

Comment: see this and you can edit here whatever you like it works http://jsfiddle.net/zNTqm/

Comment: need to selected color change with multiple item not other color change

Comment: may be this article will help you http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-multiple-option/